# Google Calendar event watch api and the 'time to live' maximum duration

Tags: events, push-notification, google-calendar-api, watch

Please may I ask if anybody can confirm that the maximum time to live when setting up push notifications using the calendar events watch api looks to be only a month?

Calling this end point:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/blah@gmail.com/events/watch

with this payload:

```
{
  "id": "blah-014",
  "token": "11223344",
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://blah.com/NotificationsFromGoogle_v1",
  "params": {
    "ttl": "157680000"
  }
}
```

Regardless of how large a number the ttl value is (greater than a month) I always get back a response with

`"expiration": nnnnnnnnn,` // Actual expiration time as Unix timestamp (in ms), if applicable.

set to a maximum of month ahead.

Answer (score 3):

The limit expiration for a notification channel is 30 days. Therefore after that time you can renew your notification channel as needed (currently there's no way to renew automatically this channel as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#renewing-notification-channels)). However if for some reason you want to stop a notification channel you should take a look to the [considerations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#stopping-notifications)

### Reference

[Renewing notification channels](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#renewing-notification-channels)

[Stopping notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#stopping-notifications)